# Does anyone know what MacBook is that?

Tags: macbook-pro

I found [this at eBay](https://www.ebay.de/itm/Macbook-air-/164516699996?_trksid=p2349624.m46890.l49292). I thought I know all MacBook Air models but never seen one like this. It looks pretty fakey to me.
Am I wrong?

Comment: Links break all the time. Please include enough information in your question so that it can stand on its own if the eBay link no longer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only MacBook models that hid the IO ports behind a door was the 1st gen MacBook Air design:

- **MacBookAir1,1**, aka **MacBook Air (original)** (2008, no longer listed on Apple's site)
- **MacBookAir2,1**, aka **MacBook Air (Mid 2009)** ([tech specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP548?locale=en_GB))

> [image: MacBook Air 2009]
>
> https://www.macstories.net/mac/the-macbook-air-a-decades-worth-of-legacy/

In 2010, the ports were moved to the side of the laptop:

> [image: MacBook Air 2010]
>
> https://www.trustedreviews.com/reviews/macbook-air-13in-late-2010

Comment: Thanks a lot. Iowas really convinced it's a fake